# SVM custom RBF kernel IndexError

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I want to implement SVM RBF kernel for my non-linearly separable data. I have defined my kernel as:

```
def rbf(va, vb):
    gamma = 0.7
    return exp(-gamma * linalg.norm(va - vb) ** 2)
clf = svm.SVC(kernel=rbf)
clf.fit(va, vb)
```

It is showing error:

> if X.shape[0] != X.shape[1]:
>   IndexError: tuple index out of range

How to resolve it?

Comment: can you print the shape of `va` and `vb` ?

Comment: va is 100x2 and vb is 100x1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shapes for `va` and `vb` are mismatching. They need to be of same shape.
The syntax for rbf kernel should be of the following form:

> def rbf(va,vb) , where `va` are the feature of sample,say X and `vb` are the features of sample say X`.

va and vb are not features and labels.

You can check [this link on Github](https://github.com/metpallyv/SVM-Kernels/blob/master/rbf_kernel.py) for similar implementation. You can see that he is passing all pairs of samples to the rbf kernel and not the features and labels of a sample. Go to line no. 95.